# Complex regex single quote replace

Tags: regex

I have a set of strings for which I would like to replace single quotes by double quotes. But, sometimes the single quote to replace is at the end of the line, sometimes the single quote should be replaced since it follow a S for possessive.

Example :

> The song 'Miss you' is featured in The Rolling Stones' album 'Voodoo Lounge'

should be

> The song "Miss you" is featured in The Rolling Stones' album "Voodoo Lounge"

Thanks your help :)

Comment: What language? What have you tried?

Comment: if your tool/language supported negative look behind: this is a dirty&quick way: `(?<!s)'`

Comment: @cappie013 I think with ruby you can try the lookbehind regex. I said it is dirty and quick, because for some case, it would fail: `Micheal Jackson's album 'Dangerous'`  the `Dangerous` is ending with `s` too.

Comment: Interesting but not sure this is possible.  How will the regex tell context?  What if there is a sentence like `The song 'Blurred Lines' is featured...`  How will it know the 's' is not a possessive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions can only deal with raw text. It can't tell context or grammar. So it is pretty much impossible to build up a regular expression that will correctly identify the occurrences of non-possessive `s` characters.

However, if you'd like to ignore such cases, and match rest of them, you can use the following regex with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!s)'(?!s\b)
```

Note that this will not match for valid cases like `Blurred Lines`, `Dangerous` etc.

[**Working demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sM6sY4/3)

Comment: This is not working with this string, for example : 
Potassium's chemical symbol is 'Pt'

Comment: @cappie013: Ah, I didn't know that was a possibility too. Updated the answer.

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you. But as @kent said with this kind of string, there's probably no solution.
Micheal Jackson's album 'Dangerous' => Indeed, impossible to know if it's a possessive S or not